# pandas dataframe O(1) index by column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and want to support O(1) index by one column. I tried `set_index` but that seems to be *not that fast* when using with `iloc`. Any thoughts on how to speed this up?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `support O(1) index by one column`

Comment: Pandas indices are effectively hash tables.  `pd.Index` can only contain hashable items.  One way to get a bit more speedup is by making sure the index doesn't contain duplicates.  I believe the getitem lookup is O(1) when both of those conditions are satisfied